# In what direction do I take this animation?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, animation, adobe-animate

I have a reference image to design my animation according to, here it is:[image]

Now my graphic is much simpler and this is how it is,

[image]

The reference animation is described as "Open hand makes a small twist in front of body.". Can someone tell me how I would go by to animate my graphic similar to how the reference graphic desires? I not asking the literal "how to do" I am simply asking someone to tell me in what shape should I drive my animation to give a similar effect to the viewer. Of course, my graphic is a vector, that I am doing inside of adobe illustrator, which I will later transfer into adobe animate to form the animation.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Doesn't the first graphic show how you would need to animate it — in a circular motion?

Comment: @BillyKerr Yes, but the problem is that my graphic has no depth so rotating it in a circular way shows as if nothing happened, so I was thinking if there was any another way or illusion to convey something like the first one?

Comment: As the arm comes towards the viewer, in 3D space, they would see the arm foreshortened slightly, and the elbow move up and down. So perhaps changing the length of the arm during the animation while moving the elbow might be enough to give the illusion. I'm no animation expert though.  Perhaps take a video of yourself doing the action, and use that as the reference for your animation.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you, I just tried your suggestion, it gives the illusion good enough, just need to add a few little details to make it look perfect. Can you please post your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it and it may help others with the same question?

Kind regards.
Sannan.

Comment: cool!  I've added it as an answer now.

Comment: I think you're both wrong @BillyKerr -- Y'all are nuts..... As I read it ... the hand remains completely *stationary* and the guy does a *back flip* over his hand.

Comment: @Scott - LOL, yeah that's  entirely  possible

Comment: @Scott what? xD not really, I managed to get this done by changing the scale of the arm as it moved as Billy said, which gave the effect good enough, on top of that, I added a drop shadow so it looked perfectly fine, at least to me :P

Comment: @Scott don't r/wooosh me if that was just a joke please 

Comment: Then I won't @Stranger 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the arm comes towards the viewer to make that circular motion, in 3D space, then the viewer would see the arm foreshortened slightly, and the elbow move up and down. So perhaps changing the length of the arm during the animation while moving the elbow might be enough to give the illusion. I'm no animation expert though.

Perhaps take a video of yourself doing the action, and use that as the reference for your animation.